# C++ Stack around the variable x was corrupted

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. I am learning some basics.
I tried the below program and got a run time error Stack around the variable x was corrupted.

```
int x = 56;
int *ptr = &x;
ptr[1]=8;
cout << *ptr << endl;
```

But if i update the index in line 3 to 0, say ptr[0] = 8, I am not getting any run time error and the console shows 8 as the output.

I assume 2 digits in the integer variable x and thought pointer index will have 0 and 1 as valid values. Why ptr[1] is causing run tume error where as ptr[2], ptr[3] does not cause any run times error and simply shows 56 as o/p.

Can any one help me to understand what is really going on here. May be a better tutorial site as an add on would help me to understand more on this subject.

Comment: Writing out of bounds leads to *undefined behaviors*, and one of the symptoms of undefined behavior is that... it seemingly works fine!

Comment: But ptr[1] is not an out of bound value here isnt it?

Comment: @funwithlinx: What's not out of bounds about it?

Comment: @funwithlinx It is out of bounds, indexing starts at `0`.

Comment: Don't learn C++ from "tutorial sites". Pick up a proper book and study it.

Comment: @funwithlinx _"I assume 2 digits in the integer variable x "_ What makes you think that numbers are stored digit wise?

Comment: Why do you think that `ptr[1]` has anything to do with digits? `[1]` is how you access the second item in an array. And `x` is not an array, so `ptr` doesn't point to an array.`

Comment: @funwithlinx With the code you show us the variable `ptr` is pointing to what can be though of as an array of a single `int` element. Using any other index than `0` will be out of bounds of this single-element array.

Answer (score 3):

ptr[1] is actually the integer next to the variable pointed to by ptr. Writing to such memory means overwriting about anything. You may overwrite other variables. Or return addresses. Or stack frames. Or about anything else. Heck, you may overwrite ptr itself, depending on how variables on the stack are arranged.

Undefined behavior. Compilers are allowed to assume it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

Let see what you are doing here (Lets assume `int` is 4 bytes):

```
int x = 56;
int *ptr = &x;
ptr[1]=8;
cout << *ptr << endl;
```

```
<- 4 bytes->......(rest of the stack)
 ----------------
|   x     |      |
 ----------------
^         ^
ptr[0]   ptr[1]
```

So, `pre[1]` is writing to a memory location which does not yet exist. So, you are writing data `out-of-bound`.

Comment: It's not that you "haven't initialised it". It's that it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you were expecting `ptr[1]` to mean the second *byte* in `x`. But that's not how pointer arithmetic works. The pointer is an `int*`, so arithmetic is performed in "chunks" of `int`-sizes. Therefore, `ptr[1]` is the non-existent integer "next to" `x`.

You could probably see this working by making `ptr` a `char*` instead, but be careful because this is real hackery and probably not a good idea unless you *really* know what you're doing.

A further misconception is your indication that the number of decimal digits in the human-readable representation of `x`'s value has anything to do with the number of bytes taking up by `x` in memory; it doesn't.

Comment: Well, at least the char* hackery is not undefined behavior as long as you don't get out of bounds (sizeof(int)).

Comment: @PaulStelian: Didn't say it was :)

Comment: Forgot to say "at least" :P